# ¿Cómo hacer para que cuando todos mis inputs tengan un borde verde activen un boton con btn.disabled = false?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario en el que tengo 8 inputs, una vez que valido que el usuario ingrese el tipo de dato que es requiero en el formulario agrego un borde verde los inputs, me gustaría que después de que todos los inputs tengan el borde verde activar un boton con btn.disabled = false.

Comment: Deberías colocar tu código.

Comment: [Te pueden votar negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices una función que se ejecute en el evento blur(por un  ejemplo) de cada input y consultar la propiedad de borde dentro de dicha función:

```
var color_inpt1 = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('content'),null).getPropertyValue('border-color')
var color_inpt2 = ...
```

Luego en la misma función consultar si el color de los input que necesites validar  son == green, entonces btn.disabled = true.